# C# How do i use a mathematical expression from an UI textbox to do calculations?

Tags: c#

I´m writing a graph plotting code to present a mathematical expression shown in a diagram. I don´t understand how to get a expression entered in a textbox to apply to further calculations? For an example: How do i replace y = x*x/128; in my code with the expression entered in a textbox? Like y = textbox.text;

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(1.0f, -1.0f); //Invert coordinatesystem on screen
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(420, -this.ClientRectangle.Height + 300); //PUT coordinate 0, 0 in the middle of screen

        int min = 0;
        int max = 250;

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.LightSteelBlue, min-400, min, max+200, min); //X1,Y1,X2;Y2
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.LightSteelBlue, min, min-250, min, max); //X1,Y1,X2;Y2

        Brush aBrush = (Brush)Brushes.LightSteelBlue;

        while (x <= max && y <= max)
        {

            y = x*x/128;

            if (y > max)
                break;

            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(aBrush, x, y, 1, 1); //x,y,width,height

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            Application.DoEvents();

            x++;
        }

        INPUT_FORMULA.Focus(); // textbox to enter formula
        INPUT_FORMULA.Select(INPUT_FORMULA.Text.Length, 0);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a string, you have to parse it. For short expressions, you can do it manualy. But for more advanced ones you should look for a library.

Comment: I´ve tried:  double.TryParse(INPUT_FORMULA.Text, out b);

Comment: int p = Convert.ToInt32(a);
                int q = Convert.ToInt32(b);

Comment: double.TryParse is only for string that represent a single double. But you have a complete formular. Parsing in general is a wide field. If you can make assumptions, like only one letter variable names and only basic operator, then may be you can try manually. Like 1) Find first operator. 2) Get part of string before it. 3) Analyse the rest... But that works only for very limited formulars. Or you have to look for a library to use.

Comment: Thanks.
I´ve corrected this and is now inputting the formula character by character in several textboxes, but it feels a little bit odd.